# How to set previous values before Going to out of the current view(onUnLoad) in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I had stored the values onLoad, after that i changed the widget properties and again before unload i want to set previously stored values, how can i do?.
Is widget.addAttachHandler(EventHandler) is helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply [design your own widget](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.in/2009/05/widget-best-practices-widget-building.html) with event listener.And in your custom widget class ovveride load and unload methods.

```
// This method is called when a widget is attached to the browser's document
  @Override
  protected void onLoad() {
    setEventListener(inputElem, this);
    // ... 
  }  


  // This method is called when a widget is detached from the browser's document 
  @Override   protected void onUnload() {
    // Clear out the inputElem's event listener (breaking the circular
    // reference between it and the widget); avoid memory leaks
    setEventListener(inputElem, null);
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: Why would you mess with the event listener to store values? This work is already done for you by `onAttach` which *calls* `onLoad` (and `onDetach` which calls `onUnload`).